# What regex to use for replacing lines in a xml file

Tags: xml, regex, eclipse, replace

I have a **large number of records** of the following type, which I have to modify

1. I would like to remove the created_by="29" line without leaving a space. Note: A wild card inside the created_by value would be preferable
2. I would like to remove the entire line creation_date="..." and the /> greater should move after state="1"/>
3. Insert a new static line before state variable (e.g. modified_by="30")

XML:

```
<user id="1"
      org_id="3"
      created_by="29"
      state="1"
      creation_date="2010-06-01"/>
```

What kind of regular expression should I use to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the attributes always appear in the same order:

search:  `(\s+)created_by="[^"]+"(\s+state="[^"]+")\s+creation_date="[^"]+"`

replace: `$1modified_by="30"$2`

If you need to specify the element name, you can add this to the beginning of the regex:

`(<user(?:\s+\w+="[^"]+")+?)`

...and change the capture-group references in the replacement like this:

`$1$2modified_by="30"$3`

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression is the wrong way to approach this problem for a whole host of reasons, many of which are outlined in [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Instead, you will find that you'll have fewer headaches if you use a proper XML parser and use [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) to identify the parts of your XML document that you want to change.

Comment: I am just trying to manipulate sample data here using Eclipse. I don't intend to do this programmatically, if its possible to resolve it using a simple search-and-replace paradigm, I will probably stick with it or else would do it manually.